# Regex - only get some of the digits

Tags: regex

I have the following text:

```
<td width="300">38.625,00</td>
```

And I only want the output: 38625

I'm using

```
[\d,]+
```

which returns 30038625,00

how can I only select the "second and third digits"?

thank you in advance

Comment: You don't have any capture groups? what language/environment are you using? What would you like for `38.625,99`?

Comment: Is this string alone or part of more HTML? If a whole HTML page must be parsed this is more troublesome

Comment: How consistent is this format?  Do you also need to be able to match things that don't have a comma in them?

Comment: Thank you for replying, It's used in Xpath to crawl webpages. I would like the 38.625,00 to be displayed as 38652 (a price to be stored)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of your circumstances, but if you want to do a replace  -

Find:  `(?<=>)(\d+)\.(\d+)(?:,\d*)?(?=</td>)`
Replace:  `$1$2`

```
 (?<= > )
 ( \d+ )                 # (1)
 \.
 ( \d+ )                 # (2)
 (?: , \d* )?
 (?= </td> )
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I have tweaked the backend part, and it can accept "." now aswell. which means \d+\.\d+ should do it. marked your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
 echo '<td width="300">38.625,00</td>' \
  | sed -nEe 's/.*[^0-9.]([0-9.]+),[0-9]{2}.*/\1/;s/[^0-9]//p'
```

Granted, that's two substitutions, but they're both based on regex.

If you always have numbers formatted as `##.###,##`, you could handle that directly, in a single regex replacement:

```
echo '<td width="300">38.625,00</td>' \
 | sed -nEe 's/.*[^0-9]([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+).*/\1\2/p'
```